# SSRS Report Showing The Size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota

Tags: size, buffer

i am developing one ssrs report using sql server 2012. i make my store procedure and called it properly and fields show in report.
now, when i am going to apply average calculation at that time. report show me error like,

"The Size necessary to buffer the XML content exceeded the buffer quota"

my input parameter is just from date, to date and location only. both date are coming from calender and for location i used dropdown.

"my average expression : =sum(Fields![column_name].Value)/COUNT(IIF(Fields![column_name].Value>0,1,Nothing))"

with this function i ignore 0 value.
kinldy please help me to solve this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not you just use [avg(columnName)] as aggregate column.

Comment: thanks siddique i solve it my self. i used 2 dataset and it show me buffer quota error so i have to pass dataset name with each expression and in average i ignore zero value.

Answer (score 0):

This because your are referencing some of the fields in the tablix which are not present in your dataset. In my case I reselected all the columns in the Tablix.

Worked fine after that.